# Adding Custom Function to OpenCPU Store

Tags: opencpu

I am trying to figure out how to add a custom function to my OpenCPU store.

I understand that we have to create an object in R/tmp.  After creating a store in /home/, Then we have to move that object from R/tmp to /home/store/ using:

PUT /home/[store name]/[object name]

It's easy to do with functions/packages already in R/pub, but when I try to do it with my own custom function, I get stuck.

I can create an R/tmp/[hashkey] object with my own custom function at this webpage, in the third form:

http://public.opencpu.org/userapps/opencpu/opencpu.demo/runcode/

Which returns:

```
{
    "object" : "x0188b9b9ce",
    "graphs" : [],
    "files" : {}
}
```

So I move this to my store via

PUT /home/[store name]/new.function

with parameter:  object = 'x0188b9b9ce'

and then I see:

```
[
 "/R/user/[user name]/[store name]/new.function"
]
```

But when I:

```
POST /R/user/[user name]/[store name]/new.function/save
```

I get this response:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Object: new.function not found in /R/user/[user name]/[store name]/
```

So what am I doing wrong?

And yes, I have replaced [user name] and [store name] with actual strings, I just wanted to keep it as straightforward as possible and clearly connected to the documentation.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. There is an issue with the host of the public server. I'm looking into it. Have you considered installing a local copy of opencpu?

Comment: I think the problem has been fixed. The new host had some weird firewall stuff that caused some issues. can you try again?

Comment: @Jeroen, thanks, I will give it a try. My site is on goDaddy, is a local copy possible?

Comment: @Jeroen what you did solved the problem, so that above works!  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeroen well it was working, but now I'm getting a lot of "cannot open the connection" errors when I'm working with new functions. Just FYI

Comment: hmm servers seems OK? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a server side problem.  Posting and using a custom function via the above will work.  Thanks to Jeroen for making the needed changes to the host server firewall.